# the raw encoding of pre-defined events in perf

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

Is there a way to figure out the raw encoding of predefined events in *perf* (a Linux profiling tool)?

For example, we use `perf stat -e instructions userexecutable` to count the number of instructions. Can *perf* shows the raw encoding of the event "instructions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at files located under `/sys/devices/cpu/events/`

Answer (score 1):

None I would be aware of. Note, that the events are processor-specific. For example, on Power8, instructions are referenced by a structure ([libpfm4 source](https://sourceforge.net/p/perfmon2/libpfm4/ci/master/tree/lib/events/power8_events.h#l3275)):

```
[ POWER8_PME_PM_INST_CMPL ] = {
    .pme_name = "PM_INST_CMPL",
    .pme_code = 0x2,
    .pme_short_desc = "Number of PowerPC Instructions that completed.",
    .pme_long_desc = "PPC Instructions Finished (completed).",
},
```

The instructions count can be gathered using

```
perf stat -e r2 userexecutable
```

For your processor, there will be similar conversion, but I don't know about any less manual way.